# A line shows always when i open my terminal on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal, command

When i open my terminal on Ubuntu, i get this error:

```
bash: export: `/home/dell/.bashrc': not a valid identifier
```

Why ? and how can i delete this line ?

[image]

Comment: When you open a terminal a set of predefined scripts run and setup some things for you. One of those scripts has an error. That's what's showing up. I'd start by looking for those scripts. Search around for bash startup scripts

Comment: How can i fix the problem exactly ? i am not expert in this things.

Comment: Show the output of `cd; cat .bashrc`.

Comment: this is what i found ans i fixed the Problem :

    # added by Anaconda3 installer
    export PATH="/home/dell/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
    export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" source /home/dell
    /.bashrc

and i made the last line as a comment and the line disappeared from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new terminal tab, the '.bashrc' script runs.
Usually, this script has some environment variables definitions, using 'export' command.

This warning shows often when export is defined with '$', like :

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/something/bin
```

Instead of

```
export PATH=$PATH:/something/bin
```

Comment: So how can i fix the problem ?

Comment: @Katty, please write here the content of ~/.bashrc file and we will try to find the problematic line in it.

Comment: It's something like this, but probably not exactly this; ".bashrc" has no business being in `PATH`. We'd have to see the actual file to get a better idea just what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i found ans i fixed the Problem :

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/dell/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" source /home/dell/.bashrc
```

and i made the last line as a comment like this:

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/dell/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" source /home/dell/.bashrc
```

and the line disappeared.

Comment: `source /home/dell/.bashrc` is probably inserted there by mistake. It's purpose is to reload the `bashrc` file without logging out and in to the shell of the terminal. if you removed just that everything will work as well. BTW - you can remove also the duplicates lines of `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` and keep only one.